# How does typecasting work and are there any size issues?

Tags: c, casting, type-conversion

I am new to c and can't seem to understand the conversion of small datatype to large datatype
e.g. converting int to char since char is just 1 byte in C while int is 4 bytes. Please explain. Thanks!

Comment: In C, char is *implicitly* promoted to `int` (or `unsigned int`) all the time, there is no need for casting. The casting itself (i.e. `(x)y` is a forceful conversion which *might* have issues.

Comment: This is quite a broad question as the typecasting can do a) promotion, b) narrowing conversion, c) no conversion; a) adding qualifiers, b) removing qualifiers; have undefined behaviour, implementation-defined behaviour, unspecified behaviour, constraint errors, aliasing errors, being no-op, etc... and then there are implicit promotions etc. Char might be signed or unsigned etc. So please if you don't get answers in the duplicates, be more specific.